# dell sonic wall vpn client and application specific access

Tags: 16.04, vpn, routing

I am using the dell sonic wall vpn desktop client.  It works fine, but I was curious if it was possible to make it so only a couple applications uses the VPN and the other applications don't.

Here is the sonic wall link
https://sslvpn.demo.sonicwall.com/cgi-bin/welcome

Any help is appreciated.  Running ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I'm having trouble connecting to NetExtender, can you you tell me  the steps you followed? I;m getting error could not resolve SSL HOST.

Comment: make a question and link me to it